# Two factor authentication doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, I want to request something from external api that is using TOTP. I have everything set up the right way and! On my localhost everything works fine, but on remote server - VPS - it crashes and gives following error :

```
{
  "status" : "success",
  "data" : {
    "error_message" : "API access enabled, but unable to verify two-factor authentication code. If you need help with this, please contact support@bitskins.com."
  }
}
```

HTML :

```
// Secret and keys for Bitskins API
                var totp = new TOTP('MPKXR23QBRQVW7SZ');
                var codeFromSecret = totp.now();

                var url = 'https://bitskins.com/api/v1/get_item_price/?api_key=' + bitskins.apikey + '&code=' + totp.now() + '&names=' + namesHashed + '&delimiter=!END!';

                console.log("url " + url);
                request(url, function (error, response, body) {
                    if (!error) {
                        var json = JSON.parse(body);
                        console.log("body " + body);
                        console.log("json " + json);
                        for (var a = 0; a < items.length; a++) {
                            itemPrices.push(json.data.prices[a].price);
                        }
                        console.log('about to emit pricesFetched @ steambot.js');
                        lastStep(itemPrices);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: have you tried `contact support@bitskins.com`?

Comment: @AndrewEvt yes, no luck so far reaching them. But as I said there must be something related to deploying this app, since it was working fine on localhost with exactly same code.